# NEW to PHP... Need Help... Regarding nested functions

Tags: php, function, nested

i'm playing around and trying to incorporate a nested function into my login script. The functions are all below. Also, beneath my functions is the portion of the login script im trying to incorporate them in. However, everytime I try to log in, it says invalid username. However if I user function a and b in the login script instead of function d, everything works fine. Can some tell me where i',m going wrong? Thanks.

```
//a -username

function username_check($username){

$usercheck = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username ='$username'";
$userqry = mysql_query($usercheck) or die ("Could not match data because ".mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($userqry);
return ($num_rows == 1) ? true : false;
}

//b - password

function password_check($password, $username){

$passwordcheck = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username ='$username'"; 
$passwordqry = mysql_query($passwordcheck) or die ("Could not match data because ".mysql_error());

while($retrievepassword = mysql_fetch_array($passwordqry))  

{

 $password = md5($password);

 return ($password != $retrievepassword['password']) ? true : false;

 }
 }
 //c    -email

 function email_check($email){

 $emailcheck = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'"; 
 $emailqry = mysql_query($emailcheck) or die ("Could not match data because ".mysql_error());
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($emailqry); 

 return ($num_rows == 1) ? true : false;
 }

 //d -username + password + email check? all in one? DOESNT WORK

 function user_check($username = NULL, $password = NULL, $email = NULL) {

 if(($email !=NULL)) {
 email_check($email);
 }

 elseif(($username !=NULL) && ($password!=NULL)){
 password_check($password,$username);   
 }

 elseif(($username !=NULL) ) {
 username_check($username);
 }

 }


 //LOGIN SCRIPT

 if (user_check($username1) ==false) { 
    $logerrors[] = 'Invalid username';

 }
 elseif (user_check($password1, $username1)) { 
    $logerrors[] = 'Incorrect password';`
```

Comment: 1: you don't nest functions. 2: break them to simpler tasks 3: `var_dump` and `print_r` are your best friends to know where you are and where you are not in the script.

Comment: What do you *expect* it to do? You're calling functions and doing nothing with the return values.

Comment: also this line `return ($password != $retrievepassword['password']) ? true : false;` your returning false when it should be true
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well for one, function d doesn't return any values.

Comment: sry i'm new to php/programming; just started 3 weeks ago. What would i return with function d? would this work?

elseif(($username !=NULL) ) {
return username_check($username);